# Is there a concept like PageMode in the Sitecore 9 Forms Editor?

Tags: sitecore-forms

Does anyone know of a concept like Sitecore.Context.PageMode inside the Sitecore 9 Forms editor?

I would like to use this in the cshtml files (Views/FormBuilder/FieldTemplates/*.cshtml) to show some additional information for editors, but it may only be vissible in the editor and not when the form is rendered on the actual page.

For info: Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsNormal == true in the forms editor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is nothing out of the box, but a `sc_formmode` url parameter is present whenever you are in Form Builder mode. The value is `new` or `edit` depending on the context, but just checking for the presence of the parameter is sufficient.

You can create an extension method to make this more reusable:

```cs
using Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers;

namespace MyCustom.Forms.Feature.ExperienceForms.Extensions
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static bool IsExperienceForms(this SitecoreHelper helper)
        {
            return Sitecore.Context.Request.QueryString["sc_formmode"] != null;
        }    
    }
}
```

In your views you can then detect the mode and render your markup as required:

```
@if (Html.Sitecore().IsExperienceForms())
{
    @* render Forms Builder mode *@
}
else
{
    @* render normal view *@
}
```

You can read more in [this blog post by Joao Neto](https://joaoneto.blog/2018/06/02/how-to-check-if-page-mode-is-experience-forms/).